Python (Dash) web app deployment on Azure with pipeline running too long with message Building wheel for pandas still running. How to optimize?
I have a Python web app (Dash) with the following requirements.txt:
dash==2.17.0
numpy==1.26.4
pandas==1.5.3
dash-mantine-components==0.14.3
python-dotenv==1.0.1
dash-iconify==0.1.2
dash-bootstrap-components==1.6.0
pyspark==3.5.1
pytz==2024.1
package @ git+https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/package
...

and within this package, this is the pipfile:
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
pandas = "==1.5.3"
pyspark = "==3.5.1"
... other dependencies

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"

And on Azure App Service, this is the configuration: Python stack with Python version 3.12.
But when I run my pipeline on Azure DevOps to build and deploy my web app, it is taking at least 20 minutes for each stage. Primarily with this step taking so long (at least around 10-12 mins):
  Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): still running...

Lastly, this is the code I used to install python dependencies in my build&deploy.yml file:
- script: |
        python -m venv antenv
        source antenv/bin/activate
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install setup
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      displayName: 'Install Python dependencies'

Furthermore, the build&deploy uses python version 3.12, versionSpec: '3.12'
Is there a way to optimize this Python app deployment on Azure with Azure DevOps pipeline? Am I doing something wrong in terms of versioning and compatibility?

I can reproduce the same issue when using pandas==1.5.3 and Python 3.12.
pandas==1.5.3 does not wheels built for your version, so your system builds them for itself each time.  It will take long time to complete. You can check the available download files from here.
To solve this issue, you can upgrade the pandas version to 2.2.2.
For example:
dash==2.17.0
numpy==1.26.4
pandas==2.2.2
dash-mantine-components==0.14.3
python-dotenv==1.0.1
dash-iconify==0.1.2
dash-bootstrap-components==1.6.0
pyspark==3.5.1
pytz==2024.1

Then the package install step will be optimized.
Result:

For more detailed info, you can refer to this release note: pandas 2.2.2
Update:
Since you are required to use pandas <2.2.0, you can use the version Pandas version 2.1.4.
For example:
pandas==2.1.4

For more detailed info, you can refer to the download files in pandas 2.1.4
Result:


Hey @KevinLu-MFST, thanks for the reply. If I am using databricks-sdk==0.27.1 and databricks-sql-connector==3.1.0, it specifies that I should have pandas<2.2.0. Does pandas<2.2.0 resolve this issue as well? Because I am getting this issue:
The conflict is caused by:     The user requested pandas==2.2.0     databricks-sql-connector 3.1.0 depends on pandas<2.2.0 and >=1.2.5; python_version >= "3.8"

@JasonSusanto You can try to use the pandas version 2.1.4 and check if it can work. For example: pandas==2.1.4 Based on my test, it also can work in ubuntu ms hosted agent.

@JasonSusanto You can refer to the update in my answer.

@KevinLu-MFST thanks for the help. I have made mine as pandas==2.1.4, Python version 3.12, databricks-sql-connector==3.1.0. And the build was only 2 minutes.

Glad to know that it can help.

@KevinLu-MFST, just wondering, as the pipeline for build & deploy is now taking 12 minutes in total, would there be a possibility to enhance it further by doing something like caching the installed dependencies so instead of running this script everytime:- script: |         python -m venv antenv         source antenv/bin/activate         python -m pip install --upgrade pip         pip install setup         pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt       displayName: 'Install Python dependencies'
The build does cache and check?

@JasonSusanto Yes. You can use the python cache in Azure Pipelines. Refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#pythonanaconda
